# multiple insert using sqlite query

Tags: sqlite

while try into multiple insert value in sqlit3  ,It showing 21 error code.

sample query:

> ```
>  insert into Assembly_master ('ASSEMBLY_MASTER_ID','ASSEMBLY_MASTER_KID','ASSEMBLY_MASTER_CODE','ASSEMBLY_MASTER_NAME','DISTRICT_MASTER_CODE','ASSEMBLY_MASTER_HINDI','DISTRICT_MASTER_KID') values ('1','1','76','HH','194',' ','1'),('2','2','101','ANGARA','1008','','545')
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement is correct, but only in [SQLite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) or later.

If you (might) have an earlier version, you should just use multiple INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the sixth value of your second insert (,'',) <-
Consecutive single quotes (doubled up like that) is SQLite's way of escaping a single quote (quoting from SQL As Understood By SQLite -> [HERE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row - as in Pascal.

This leaves a single quote character (not surrounded by single quotes) as the placeholder to be handled by SQLite, instead of the expected string constant ...and thus... the Error code 21 ( SQLITE_MISUSE ) is generated when binding is attempted.

Perhaps you intended the space character ' ' or NULL?

**EDIT:**
Despite this answer being **~obviously wrong~** , the info within this answer is an SQLite "gotcha" that likely does not get much mention, so I hope it helps anyone who lands here via related search terms.

Comment: You overlooked "*within the string*"; a pair of single quotes `''` alone is just an empty string.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I saw the OP's sixth value intentioned to be the same for each insert and "presumed" without actually running the code statement. Thanks and glad you pointed up his problem.